# Generate method or class comments in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, comments

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1. I can hit `fix doc comment` to insert comment of method quickly in Java, but not effective in Kotlin. How can I solve it?

Comment: found an answer here?

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin and especially [KDoc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html) encourage a different documentation style. As stated in this [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/autocomplete-method-documentation-template-in-intellij/1905):

> The reason is that we found that referring to parameter names from the documentation text allows to write documentation that is more concise and easier to read compared to the traditional javadoc style where *every parameter is documented in a separate tag*. Therefore, **we do not generate the template with parameter names by default**. (D. Jemerov, Kotlin in Action Author)

Here’s an example of [`let`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L91), which is part of the standard library:

```
/**
 * Calls the specified function [block] with `this` value as its argument and returns its result.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're typing `@` inside a `kdoc`, you'll see auto complete for `@param`, and after `@param` you'll see all parameters, and currently you cannot complete all parameters within one click.

Mention the `/** */` comments are called `kdoc` in Kotlin, which is not `javadoc`.